Delta Live Table missing data
Got a very simple DLT which runs fine, but the final table "a" is missing data.

I've found that after performing a full refresh live above, if I rerun just the final table, then I get more records (from 1.2m to 1.4m) and the missing data then comes back.

When I run the last bit of the code in a notebook manually then I do get all the records, so I don't know where the 1.2m comes from.  I feel like it's somehow reading an older version of the r and c tables, but that shouldn't be happening if it's a full refresh right?
I've also noticed that I get the following warning:
 Your query 'r' reads from '<catalog name>.<schema name>.p' but must read from 'LIVE.p' instead. Always use the LIVE keyword when referencing tables from the same pipeline so that DLT can track the dependencies in the pipeline.
But in the code in my notebook I already use LIVE. and don't reference any catalog or schema.

There are three things. Here are the details:

The table, if defined as Live.table_name, the DLT assumes that the DLT pipeline manages this table.
If defined as catalog_name.schema_name.table_name. The DLT interprets as a reference to the external table.
Finally, when you have the same table name in both scenarios and if you miss LIVE. prefix in your code, which causes ambiguity and gives warnings.

Please let me know if you need any more information.
